# Javascript (Angular) nested directive loading twice due to $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, compilation

I have a directive nested within a directive. To satisfy our designers needs I require the contents to be direct children of the DOM node.

```
  <div>
    <my-directive style="color: blue;">

      <p>Name: {{ ctl_a.fname }} {{ ctl_a.sname }}</p>
      <p>External Test: {{ xternal }}</p>

      <div>
        <nested-directive incoming="ctl_a.a_counter"></nested-directive>
      </div>

    </my-directive>
  </div>
```

What are my best options for getting this to load correctly? I.E "my-directive" can access ctl_a.fname, and "nested-directive" can access $scope.incoming, as the argument passed in by "ctl_a.a_counter".

[Here is a plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Yea2qv4Stop8VAGF9QQK?p=preview) that demonstrates the problems I am running in to using $compile. If I use $compile, the nested directives execute twice. Once for the outer directive compile method, and once again for the manual one. Worse still the manual one is the only one that appears to render the contents correctly.

If I use `ng-transclude` then none of attributes passed to the inner directive work without prefixing with $$prevSibling or $parent because ng-transclude appears to create a new scope. This seems to be fundamentally wrong having to reference it like that.

**Edit:** Here is [another plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/0oqKQXA3arFpt9Ju0qJ7?p=preview) which forks the first one. This time i'm demonstrating ng-transclude and how I need to use $parent to access the controller for its directive.

Thanks.

Comment: So why do you let Angular compile the content if you eventually compile it yourself? Also I'm not sure what's your actual question.

Comment: _What are my best options for getting this to load correctly?_ As in, How do I have angular process this markup so that the template variables are evaluated in context of their containing directives. Because angular will not compile these like this as they currently stand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's all you want to know, but you need to add `terminal: true` to your directive definition object. This prevents Angular from processing the HTML within the `my-directive` tags until you compile it yourself. Modified code from your plunker:

```
function myDirective($compile) {
  var directive = {
        compile: compile,
        controller: controller,
        controllerAs: 'ctl_a',
        replace: true,
        terminal:true, //<=======
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '='
        }
    };

    return directive;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I never knew about "terminal". This stops the digest loop compiling the content and giving me null variables. Thanks so much!

Comment: About 10 minutes ago I also found a way to achieve this using ng-transclude utilising javascript capabilities to attach properties to objects by reference. I will post my findings here as an alternate solution too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not using data property of my-directive. You can remove below code from my-directive.

```
    scope:{
        data: '='
     }
```

Now you do not need to manually compile as below. So remove it also.

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

Working [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/3bTLX56qFMNWfhS6HBYe?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I am not using data, but its a demonstration that I need an isolated scope, and that I will be passing stuff in. The only reason your plunk works is because you've removed the scope isolation. Here is a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/taxVe8OWTdNq1qDQb8jr?p=preview) demonstrating an argument called "arg" being injected.